# Apache httpclient returning page before it loads?

Tags: java, apache, httpclient

I noticed a strange phenomenon when using the apache httpclient libraries and I want to know why it occurs. I created some sample code to demonstrate.
Consider the following code:

```
//Example URL
 String url = "http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/05961580/ref=dp_olp_used?ie=UTF8";
 GetMethod get = new GetMethod(url);
 HttpMethodRetryHandler httpHandler = new DefaultHttpMethodRetryHandler(1, false);
 get.getParams().setParameter(HttpMethodParams.RETRY_HANDLER, httpHandler );
 get.getParams().setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.IGNORE_COOKIES);
 HttpConnectionManager connectionManager = new SimpleHttpConnectionManager();
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient( connectionManager );
 client.getParams().setParameter("http.useragent", FIREFOX );
 String line;
 StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
 String toStreamBody = null;
 String toStringBody = null;
 try {
  int statusCode = client.executeMethod(get);
  if( statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK ){
   System.err.println("Internet Status: " + HttpStatus.getStatusText(statusCode) );
   System.err.println("While getting page: " + url );
  }
 //toString
  toStringBody = get.getResponseBodyAsString();
 //toStream
  InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(get.getResponseBodyAsStream())
  BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(isr);
  while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
  stringBuilder.append(line);
  }
 } catch (java.io.IOException ex) {
  System.out.println( "Failed to get page: " + url);
 } finally {
  get.releaseConnection();
 }       
 toStreamBody = stringBuilder.toString();
```

This code prints nothing:

```
 System.out.println(toStringBody); // ""
```

This code prints the web page:

```
 System.out.println(toStreamBody); // "Whole Page"
```

But it gets even stranger...
Replace:

```
get.getResponseBodyAsString();
```

With:

```
 get.getResponseBodyAsString(150000);
```

Now we get the error:
Failed to get page: `http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/0596158068/ref=dp_olp_used?ie=UTF8`

I was unable to find another website besides for amazon that replicates this behavior but I assume there are others.

I am aware that according to the documentation at `http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/performance.html` discourages the use of `getResponseBodyAsString()`, it does not say that the page will not load, only that you may be at risk of an out of memory exception. Is it possible that `getResponseBodyAsString()` is returning the page before it loads? Why does this only happen with amazon?

Answer (score 0):

Did you test with any other URL?

The URL in code that you provided redirects with 302 to http://www.amazon.com/dp/05961580/?tag=stackoverfl08-20, which then returns 404 (not found).

HttpClient does not handle redirects: http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/redirects.html

Comment: Oh that's not the link. I'll try to change it back.

Comment: The site is http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/0596158068/ref=dp_olp_used?ie=UTF8

Comment: Ok, for some reason thee site gets changed by the website. There's nothing I can do about that.